# Position the cursor to end of line

Tags: informix, 4gl

I am trying to validate an input, if invalid; I want to return to that field but to the end of the line.

I don't want the cursor to jump to the beginning of the line. Rather, to the end.

Any idea?

I moved my code from "after field" to "on key (return)" but the field name doesn't have the value at that point. And my C function gives me problems to get it from the buffer.

Comment: The get_fldbuf() function worked to get the data from the buffer, but the cursor is jumping to the beginning of the line when using "display m_array.string to s_array.string"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Genero, we added fgl_dialog_setcursor() http://4js.com/online_documentation/fjs-fgl-manual-html/index.html#c_fgl_BuiltInFunctions_FGL_DIALOG_SETCURSOR.html to do that, which suggests that what you are after was not easily possible in 4gl

Comment: Hey Reuben! I'm using genero, Do you know if there's any way to position a textedit vertical scrollbar at the end? I tried to use FGL_DIALOG_SETCURSOR, but it didn't really work. Any help would be appreciated

Comment: A quick test revealed that FGL_DIALOG_SETCURSOR also works with TEXTEDIT.  I did observe that this call had to be in BEFORE FIELD, it didn't work if in BEFORE INPUT.  If you get different results, I suggest you create a small MVCE for your support contact.

Comment: Yeah, it turns out that the problem was that I was rendering HTML tags in the TextEdit, after some changes it worked well. Thanks for the reply